# Multi-lines text in mathjax for android

Tags: javascript, android, mathjax

I have a project android with mathjax and I found code mathjax for android here `cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=585`

I changed the code to consistent with my project and now it is working but mathjax not auto multi-lines text when full-width

My code:

```
WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            String data = "x=\\frac{-b\\pm\\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} I LOVE ANDROID";
            mmltoggle=false;

            w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('mmlout').innerHTML='';");
            w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                       +doubleEscapeTeX(data)+"\\\\]';");
            w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
```

output:

[i.stack.imgur.com/z7iyl.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7iyl.png)

(non whitespaces in text "I LOVE ANDROID" and text in mathjax not auto multi-lines when full-width)

I want to output:

[i.stack.imgur.com/egJh0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egJh0.png)

I tried with \u00A0 and "~"  but texts not multi-lines.

Please help, thanks !

p/s: Sr, my english is not good

Comment: Both `\u00A0` and `~` (in TeX) produce *non*-breaking spaces, so this certainly would not work.

Answer (score 1):

MathJax used MathML as its internal format, and in MathML, equation breaks only occur at `<mo>` (math operator) and `<mspace>` (math space) elements.  The "text" that you give has only `<mi>` elements, so contains no valid breakpoints.

You could define

```
\def\allowbreak{\mmlToken{mo}{}}
```

and then use

```
data = "x=\\frac{-b\\pm\\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} I LOVE \allowbreak ANDROID";
```

but you still won't get the spaces between the words, and the underlying MathML is not semantically correct.

Why are you including this text in your mathematics anyway?  Shouldn't this just be plain HTML text and not math?  Perhaps your data should be

```
data = "\\[x=\\frac{-b\\pm\\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\] I LOVE ANDROID";
```

and you don't add the delimiters automatically in the code.